# Display images dynamicalli in objective -c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, dynamic, displaytag

I want images to be displayed dynamically, for ex- if user selects 10 images, all those should get displayed, now if user wants to select 5 more images, so (10+5) 15 images should get displayed. How to achieve this functionality?

I am using UIImagePickerController to select images, so at a time user will be able to select 1 image only.I have given a add photo button.

```
 UIImagePickerController *galleryObj=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    galleryObj.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    galleryObj.allowsEditing = YES;
    galleryObj.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:galleryObj animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Above will get executed when user taps on add photo button.

Comment: When user select the image from library, you can store that image or image url in array.

Comment: How to add images dynamically to an array???

Comment: Ketan, are you still confused? Let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//`GalleryViewcontroller.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GallaryViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *selectedImagesArray;
}
@end
```

`GalleryViewcontroller.m`

```
@implementation GallaryViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //allocating array
    selectedImagesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}


-(IBAction)openGallery:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *galleryObj=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    galleryObj.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    galleryObj.allowsEditing = YES;
    galleryObj.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:galleryObj animated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark UIImagePickerController Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{


        //here we are adding the image in array
        [selectedImagesArray addObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        NSLog(@"%@",selectedImagesArray);

        //reload your colleciton view or tableview or any other view which your using to show selected images

        //you can get images by index
        //UIImage *img=[selectedImagesArray objectAtIndex:0];


    }];
}
@end
```